# How to write reliable tests spawning processes?

Tags: testing

I'm looking for better ways to write my integration tests which spawn processes and tests their stdouts. My project is a commandline application, or rather two applications communicating via TCP. They typically run without ending, so I have to kill them at some point during the tests. The tests I am writing are usually structured like this:

1. Create processes with desired arguments.
2. Sleep for 50ms to let them communicate.
3. Kill the processes.
4. Get their stdout and verify that some lines were (or weren't) printed.

This is obviously not ideal, because the sleep duration could be too small and the test will fail or it could be too big and the test will waste time.

Is it possible to write the tests spawning processes in a safe manner without heavily altering the tested applications?

Example of the actual code is here: https://github.com/DziubanMaciej/CheckMate/blob/14c7d6d7e772fb90b5c78abe70453d3ccfacda26/tests/tests.rs#L180

Comment: As a general idea (might not be easy to implement in your case): instead of running test, waiting, killing, checking output let the test actively monitor the output while the server is running/communicating and kill the server as soon as the test found the desired output. (with a timeout for the case the output never appears)